# meson and git information

Tags: meson-build

I need to provide to the binary built with meson build system some git information regarding branch and version used:

```
git describe --tags
git descibe --help
```

the problem I have is how retrieve this information with meson,

with the make build I use the following instruction:

```
GITREF = $(shell git describe --all)
LIB1_VER = $(shell cd ../../lib1;git describe --tags;cd - &>NULL)
```

so in meson for GITREF  I've tried

```
info_dep = vcs_tag(command : ['git descibe --all'],
            input : 'infoBuild.h.in',
            output : 'infoBuild.h',
            replace_string : 'BRANCHNAME')
```

where infobuild.h.in is:

```
#define GITREF "BRANCHNAME"
```

but when I go to compile with ninja I got

```
 /usr/local/bin/meson --internal vcstagger ../../src/prog1/info/infoBuild.h.in src/prog1/info/infoBuild.h 1.1.0 /home/mariano/clonesIntel/projMes/src/prog1/info BRANCHNAME '(.*)' '/home/mariano/clonesIntel/ProjMes/src/prog1/info/git describe --all'
```

but I don't find any infoBuild.h,
more over for the LIB1_VER is more difficult because it is in an external folder,
I could overcome this issue with a bash script but is there  a way to retrieve both information in meson build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an immediate problem in that it's going to try to run a command `'git describe --all'`, which is not what you want, as meson will be sure to escape the spaces in your shell so that it treats that as the a single filename, you want `['git', 'describe', '--all']`. Of course, that could just be a type in your example.

One option you might consider is a [`run_command`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#run_command) and configure_file, which is a command run at compile time, and produces a result object that you can get string values from. The disadvantage of this compared to vcs_tag (or a custom_target) is that it happens at configure time, as opposed to build time, so you need to reconfigure to update your tags:

```
res = run_command(['git', 'describe', '--all'], capture : true, check : true)
describe = res.stdout()

version_h = configure_file(
  input : 'version.h.in',
  output : 'version.h',
  configuration : {'PLACEHOLDER' : describe}
)
```